# How to write to an IndexBuffer3D with uploadFromByteArray(...)

Tags: flash, format, arrays, shader, stage3d

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong, but according to Adobe, this is how you use `uploadFromByteArray(...)` on an IndexBuffer3D object:

- [Adobe's LiveDocs for IndexBuffer3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display3D/IndexBuffer3D.html#uploadFromByteArray%28%29)

What I don't understand is which writing-method do I have to use to write the integers of my vertex-indexes? I've tried `writeFloat`, `writeUnsignedInt`, `writeInt`, even `writeShort` and all fails. I've set my ByteArray instance to `ba.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN`, still no go.

I've made sure to reset my ByteArray position to 0 before I attempt to upload it to my index-buffer, but **nothing shows up!**

If I upload a `Vector.<uint>` instead, that works! So I know the problem is not with the AGAL shader.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, just found what I was doing wrong:

**WRONG**:

```
_buffer.uploadFromByteArray(_dataBytes, 0, 0, _dataBytes.length >> 2);
```

I was dividing by 4 at first (bitwise-shift twice is the same) because I though the number of bytes per index was 4 bytes long. Nah ah! Incorrect!

ByteArrays for IndexBuffer3D purposes should be written with `writeShort()`, since it utilizes 16-bit numbers instead of 32-bit. Therefore, it only uses 2 bytes per indexes.

**CORRECT**:

```
_buffer.uploadFromByteArray(_dataBytes, 0, 0, _dataBytes.length >> 1);
```

Hope that clarifies it up for other Stage3D users! :)